# breaking up multi string into multiple lines json

Tags: json

I am building a template for people to create quizzes that dont have coding experience. So i am trying the easiest way for people to update a json file. I cannot figure out how to break the options into multiple lines. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
"1" : {
        "question": [
            "Pittsburgh is home to the first Cable Suspension Bridge.",
            "A: somewhat true", 
            "B: likely true",
            "C: always true",
            "D: completely false"
            ],


        "answer": "c"
    },

    "2" : {
        "question": [
            "Pittsburgh is home to the first Cable Suspension Bridge.",
            "A: somewhat true", 
            "B: likely true",
            "C: always true",
            "D: completely false"
            ],

        "answer": "c"
    },

    "3" : {
        "question": [
            "Pittsburgh is home to the first Cable Suspension Bridge.",
            "A: somewhat true", 
            "B: likely true",
            "C: always true",
            "D: completely false"
            ],

        "answer": "c"
    },
```

Comment: Hey, Julianne, what exactly do you mean by, "break the options into multiple lines?" Also, are you sure you want to put the answer alongside each question?

Comment: I want each option to be on a different line, just as it reads. If there is a better option for the answer, as of right now that works. I just cant get the question to display properly. Its all one line.

Comment: That would depend on what is displaying this data and whether you put newline characters `\n` in the JSON. Is this displayed in a web page? If so, this is a HTML/CSS question that would require minimal code to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Try this json structure

```
{
  "quiz":[{
    "question":"Pittsburgh is home to the first Cable Suspension Bridge.",
    "options":["somewhat true","likely true","always true","completely false"],
    "answer":"c"
  },
  {
    "question":"Pittsburgh is home to the first Cable Suspension Bridge.",
    "options":["somewhat true","likely true","always true","completely false"],
    "answer":"c"
  },
  {
    "question":"Pittsburgh is home to the first Cable Suspension Bridge.",
    "options":["somewhat true","likely true","always true","completely false"],
    "answer":"c"
  }]
}
```

It's seems to working fine as it contains a separation between question,answer and options available. If you want to maintian multiple quizzes wrap this json structure into an array.

```
{
  "quizzes":[{
    "quiz":[{
      "question":"Pittsburgh is home to the first Cable Suspension Bridge.",
      "options":["somewhat true","likely true","always true","completely false"],
      "answer":"c"
    },
    {
      "question":"Pittsburgh is home to the first Cable Suspension Bridge.",
      "options":["somewhat true","likely true","always true","completely false"],
      "answer":"c"
    },
    {
      "question":"Pittsburgh is home to the first Cable Suspension Bridge.",
      "options":["somewhat true","likely true","always true","completely false"],
      "answer":"c"
    }]
  }]
}
```